# How to set preload images to its corresponding place?

Tags: javascript, html

I met such a problem recently and do not how to figure it out. I have an HTML image table:

1. The number of table rows will change dynamically without page refresh according to user input
2. Each row in the table contains one special image in the database
3. I want to load image for rows that're displayer (many other rows are hidden so I don't want to load image for them)

I found a snippet like the following:

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg')
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#something").append(img);
        }
    });
```

but the problem is that, on the .load method, the image itself will forget where it should be placed (because I use for loop to load the image row by row in the table)

Is there anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I assume that `$("#something")` is the row where the image should be added?

Comment: yes. but as the row number is not fixed, so what I can pass in is a variable like 'i' in the 'for i=0;i<rows.length;i++' loop. That is to say, when the .load method is executed after the image is loaded, the variable 'i' has already changed...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to correlate the image with its row. If you have the row at hand when creating the image, you can use it in the callback to `.load`. For example, if at some point you have a list of new rows, you can do something like this:

```
var loadImageForRow = function(row) { 
    var img = $("<img/>").attr('src', 'my-image-source.png')
        .load(function() { 
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == 'undefined' || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                // handle broken image
            } else {
                 row.find('.image-cell').append(img);
            }
        });
});

newRows.each(function() { loadImageForRow($(this)); }
```

This uses the `row` parameter from the enclosing closure inside the callback. Alternatively, you can correlate the two using data attributes on the image or on the row (e.g. put something like `data-row-index='17'` on the `img` element) or any equivalent mechanism.

Comment: Hi Avish, thank you so so much for your help! I'll try and let you know if it works for me.